# How to test if I have Composer?

Tags: php

I hire a shared hosting to host my website.

I can SSH into that environment.

How could I test if I have PHP Composer on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just type `composer` in Terminal.

If the composer has been installed, it will output the version and a quick manual. Otherwise, it will display an error message like: `bash: composer: command not found`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).